# GNOME tracker loses all indexed files

Tags: gnome, mount, fstab, tracker

I've recently installed 21.04 on an SSD with my personal files on a separate HDD formatted as exFAT so that it can be used by both Ubuntu and Windows on a dual boot system. This HDD is configured in fstab to mount automatically when I boot into Ubuntu with the settings "rw,exec,umask=000" which, I think, is fully permissive. I also have symbolic links from my Ubuntu home folder to the HDD (i.e. Desktop, Downloads, Music, etc are symlinks between drives). Tracker has been having issues indexing and persisting it's indexed files. As a result, all the programs that depend on it, like gnome-music, gnome videos, gnome-games-app, gnome-photos, etc don't work consistently. That is to say, they *sometimes* work. For example, after a reboot I opened a terminal and issued the same command sequentially.

[tracker status changed unexpectedly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmMuV.png)

Immediately after login the tracker had 11 thousand files indexed. I tested this in gnome-music by successfully playing a song. Only a few moments later, the app failed and the same tracker status command shows 0 indexed files. Where'd they go?

I have modified one property d-conf for indexing removable media on some advice I found elsewhere on the net. But I have experienced this same problem before changing the property. The specific property is "index-removable-devices"

[one modified tracker property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9rog.png)

I doubt that change has anything to do with it though I suspect the removable media is an issue. Of course I have alternatives (like Lollypop) but I would like to have tracker functioning properly since, for one thing, Rygel depends on it and I want to use it as my home media server. Any suggestions about how to use tracker correctly are welcome.

Comment: I have the same issue. Looks like a tracker bug to me, but when googling I could only find this post here.

Comment: I opened a bug report now with  the tracker project https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/tracker/-/issues/328
Looks like Ubuntu 21.04 is using an outdated Tracker version.